# How to use React Context API with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-context

I have a react redux application that I want to use React Context API for one of the things I'm trying to do

so I have this

```
<Provider value="something" store={store}>
      // stuff in here
</Provider>
```

which works fine but then I tried to add context

```
const AppTypeContext = React.createContext('someContext' as any)

<AppTypeContext.Provider value="myValue" store={store}>
      // stuff in here
</AppTypeContext.Provider>
```

then my app threw an error saying `Property 'store' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<any>'.  TS2322`

how do I fix this? and what provider do I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app can have [multiple contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts).

Just separate properly the provided values:

- `store` is to be provided via `Provider`
- `"something"` should be provided by your `AppTypeContext.Provider`.

```
<Provider store={store}>                      // redux provider
  <AppTypeContext.Provider value="something"> // your provider
     {children}
  </AppTypeContext.Provider>
</Provider>
```

Comment: right I thought that would be the case and I swear I tried this. anyway, looks like it worked. thanks!

Comment: thanks. do I have to wrap every component inside <Consumer> if I have many children or nested children then it seems overkill to wrap them all in this and will require many changes to my app?

Comment: You can use the static [`contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype)

Comment: but what if my contextType changes?  and  also I have to import that into all my components inside my app? seems like context doesn't scale very well

Comment: Please read through [when to use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context). If it doesn't fit your design, probably you would need to make use of `redux`.